# How to config static VM with DHCP service started?

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp, pxe, httpd

everyone.

I am newbie on Unix.

Here I set up a VM in VMware.At first it can go on web with static IP and default NAT DHCP which provided by VMware.

And then I seted up cobbler to install system, so I stopped the default NAT DHCP and started DHCP on this VM.

After I installed system, I find I cannot connect the Internet.It can ping to the host which runs this VM but that's all.It cannot reach the host network gateway.

What should I do then ?

I tried to set gateway using its IP but nothing happened.

Thanks.

==============================================================

My OS: Win7
My VM software : VMware 14
My VM Machine : Centos7

==================================================================

I figure it out now.
I used wireless network recently and I forgot to change the DNS in ifcfg-eth0 which is link to the next gateway...

Comment: What is your host OS?  What is your guest OS?  What VMware product are you using?

Comment: How to close this post....

Answer (score 0):

Please don't think that I am making fun of your English or network knowledge, but I genuinely have a problem understanding what you are doing. The questions and assumptions that I make are too big to fit into a comment, so I am abusing an answer for it.

> > Here I set up a VM in VMware.At first it can go on web with static IP and default NAT DHCP which provided by VMware.

This is incomprehensible. Did you get a static IP address for your machine, or do you get it from DHCP? In both cases, the IP address is determined by the network that you are on. If it is static, you should have been given an IP address, netmask and gateway. If it is via DHCP, you would have been given the same information, only via DHCP.

The information of IP address, netmask and gateway is vital for connecting to the outside world.

You now started a DHCP server on the local network. Did you give your local interfaces a fixed IP address (namely the address that you got to connect to the outside world)? In general, you DHCP server wil not get it's IP address via DHCP.

So what was the output from `ifconfig` and `netstat -rn` before you disabled DHCP? And what was the output after that? If the output is the same, then it should connect (via NAT) to the outside world.

So, what does your network look like? Can you give a specific network picture? With IP addresses, so that they can be verified?

Comment: I figure it out now. I used wireless network recently and I forgot to change the DNS in ifcfg-eth0 which is link to the next gateway...